# ORACLE moving user messages into appropriate directories depending on time of arrival

Tags: oracle

My simplified table structure looks like this:

```
MESSAGES(Id NUMBER,Content NVARCHAR2, Received_time TIMESTAMP)

DIRECTORIES(Id NUMBER, Name NVARCHAR2, PARENT NUMBER)

MESSAGES_USERS(Id NUMBER, MSG NUMBER (FK MESSAGES(Id)), USER NUMBER, DIRECTORY NUMBER (FK DIRECTORIES(Id)))
```

So, the task is to move messages into apropriate directories depending on received time. It is achieved by updating MASSAGES_USERS table and changing DIRECTORY id.
Prepared directory structure looks like this:

```
2012--
     |
     --- 04/2012
     |
     --- 05/2012 
     |
     --- 06/2012
```

So that I`ll have to move messages received in april 2012 into directory named 04 which is a descendant of directory named 2012 in current users directory structure. 
I search for the directory by name using

```
name LIKE TO_CHAR(M.Received_time, 'MM')||'/'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.Received_time)
```

Is there any way to update directory for every message in one UPDATE statement without using a cursor? I've tried some corelated updates, but none of them (even with some huge subqueries) is a proper solution.

The statement should get appropriate directory id using message receival time (It requeries joining these three tables) and UPDATE DIRECTORY field in MESSAGES_USERS table with appropriate reveived id.

I have no idea how to force oracle to update every message with appropiate directory without specifing id of one message using cursor loop. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
update messages_users mu
set directory = 
( select d.id from directories d
  join messages m on d.name = to_char(m.receved_time, 'MM/YYYY')
  where m.id = mu.msg );
```

Comment: Edited - incorporated improvement from Vincent Malgrat's deleted answer!

Comment: The point is good, but id doesn't consider whose messages to move and it messed up a bit the messages structure and moved everyones messages into my folders, but I rolledback :) I have user id in a parameter called P_WHO and I also have to check it. But it pushed me in a good direction.

Comment: A simple WHERE statement after that fixed my issue, so it's a well deserved accept. Thanks!